# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(a)')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I have a firebase file where I've storing all my config data

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
```

add firebase config

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};
```

initialize firebase

```
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

initialize auth

```
const auth = getAuth();

export { auth };
```

I have a home page calling the config file but I keep getting the same error I've made sure to check if I'm importing it properly

```
import auth from '../config'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';



export const HomeScreen = () => {

  if(!firebase.apps.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(auth);
}
```

Call Stack

```
    This error is located at:
        in HomeScreen (created by SceneView)
        in StaticContainer
        in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
        in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by Screen)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by Background)
        in Background (created by Screen)
        in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
        in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
        in AnimatedComponent
        in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
        in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
        in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
        in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
        in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
        in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
        in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
        in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
        in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
        in BottomTabNavigator (created by MainStackScreens)
        in MainStackScreens (created by SceneView)
        in StaticContainer
        in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
        in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by CardContainer)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by CardContainer)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View
        in CardSheet (created by Card)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
        in AnimatedComponent
        in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler)
        in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
        in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
        in AnimatedComponent
        in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by Card)
        in Card (created by CardContainer)
        in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
        in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
        in AnimatedComponent
        in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
        in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
        in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
        in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
        in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
        in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by Background)
        in Background (created by CardStack)
        in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
        in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
        in GestureHandlerRootView
        in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
        in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
        in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
        in StackNavigator (created by AppStack)
        in AppStack (created by RootNavigator)
        in EnsureSingleNavigator
        in BaseNavigationContainer
        in ThemeProvider
        in NavigationContainerInner (created by RootNavigator)
        in RootNavigator (created by App)
        in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
        in SafeAreaProvider (created by App)
        in AuthenticatedUserProvider (created by App)
        in App (created by ExpoRoot)
        in ExpoRoot
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by AppContainer)
        in RCTView (created by View)
        in View (created by AppContainer)
        in AppContainer
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:34:4 in console.error
    at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15792:34 in logCapturedError
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15884:20 in update.callback
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7199:2 in callCallback
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7220:20 in commitUpdateQueue
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16632:25 in commitLifeCycles
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19216:22 in commitLayoutEffects
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:93:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackProd
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:318:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18952:29 in commitRootImpl
    at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:468:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18791:17 in commitRoot
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18192:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5911:33 in runWithPriority$argument_1
    at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:468:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5906:23 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5893:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17745:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11332:25 in dispatchAction
    at navigation\RootNavigator.js:23:20 in onAuthStateChanged$argument_1
    at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
    at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:177:14 in _callImmediatesPass
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:437:30 in callImmediates
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:388:6 in __callImmediates
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:132:6 in __guard$argument_0
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:131:4 in flushedQueue
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error? (All the junk stuff printed after the error starting with `at`).

Comment: If that's the entirety of your firebase config file you're not exporting anything from it

Comment: @Phix yes that is the entire firebase config it worked when I did the registerscreen

Answer (score 0):

```
export const auth = getAuth();

import {auth} from '../config'
```

Comment: I've done this already and I get [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app).]

Comment: Please add an explanation why you think this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you export it like you mentioned:

```
const auth = getAuth();

export { auth };
```

you should import it be like:
`import {auth} from "../config"`

Comment: I've done this already and I get [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app).]